# How to switch the Style of a Border depending on a bool in wpf (mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So This is (a part of) my border in the xaml

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FunctionProviderViewModel}">
    <Border Margin="4"
            Background="PapayaWhip"
            CornerRadius="4"                
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsSimpleModeActive}"
            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AcpBorder}">
```

Im populating a Control with this DataTemplate. I added another Border with `x:Key="SimpleAcpBorder"` and i added a bool to my viewmodel (which will is bound to a checkbox). Now i want to set the style to simple if the checkbox is checked and to regular else. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

my datatemplate looks like this now

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FunctionProviderViewModel}">
    <Border Background="PapayaWhip">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border"                       
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AcpBorder}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSimpleModeActive}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Margin"
                                Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius"
                                Value="0" />                            
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>

        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="5" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <TreeViewItem VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                      Background="Transparent"
```

and in another xaml my AcpBoarder stays untouched:

```
    <Style x:Key="AcpBorder"
       TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius"
            Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="2" />
</Style>
```

But somehow the Trigger doesnt seem to work for me. Any ideas?

Thank you very much

EDIT2:

```
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=54724182) for    Binding (hash=28450086)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'IsSimpleModeActive'
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): Default mode resolved to OneWay
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): Attach to         System.Windows.Controls.Border.NoTarget (hash=22755592)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): Resolving source 
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): Found data context element: Border (hash=22755592) (OK)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): Activate with root item FunctionProviderViewModel (hash=3473742)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182):   At level 0 using cached accessor for FunctionProviderViewModel.IsSimpleModeActive: RuntimePropertyInfo(IsSimpleModeActive)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): Replace item at level 0 with FunctionProviderViewModel (hash=3473742), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsSimpleModeActive)
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): GetValue at level 0 from FunctionProviderViewModel (hash=3473742) using RuntimePropertyInfo(IsSimpleModeActive): 'False'
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=54724182): TransferValue - using final value 'False'
The thread '' (0x454) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Instead of trying to do this using two separate styles, why not have just one (say "AcpBorder") which includes a data trigger (bound to your bool property) that changes the necessary properties, resulting in the "simple" border appearance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` for this. However, you cannot apply a `DataTrigger` directly to your border. Instead you have to apply it to a `Style`.

From the comments it seems that you use the style `AcpBorder` in many places and you do not want to create a coupling between this style and a view-model property named `IsSimpleModeActive`. One way to do that is to set the `Border.Style` property directly and let the style be based on the `AcpBorder` style:

```
<Border Margin="4" Background="PapayaWhip" CornerRadius="4" IsEnabled="False">
  <Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource AcpBorder}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSimpleModeActive}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>

          ... more setters

        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question: where do i have to put the <Style> </Style> element? outside of my <DataTemplate/> ?

Comment: @user3596113: You can simply modify your `AcpBorder` style which you are already using. For a named style to be usable in the `Border` the `ResourceDictionary` has to be "above" the `Border` in the XAML "hierarchy" (this goes as far as the `Appliction.Resources`). You can also directly set the `Style` property of `Border` instead of referencing a named style but then you cannot reuse the style.

Comment: But my AcpBorder style element is placed in another xaml file. The Binding to the IsSimpleModeActive property wont work then, will it?

Comment: @user3596113: The binding will work of the `DataContext` of the `Border` has that property. However, I assume that you use the `AcpBorder` style in places where that assumption is not true. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately the trigger doesnt seem to work for me. I will edit my post in a second, could you please have a look on it?

Comment: @user3596113: Does the object having the `IsSimpleModeActive` fire change notifications? E.g., does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly? You should verify that the binding is OK. Change it to something like `Binding="{Binding IsSimpleModeActive, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"` and watch the output when running in a debugger.

Comment: okay im getting warnings now, i didnt get before. Please see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58787/discussion-between-martin-liversage-and-user3596113).